# Exclude Sticky posts from Main Query break Pagination

Tags: sticky-post, plugin-wp-pagenavi

I have a small problem with this function ! I would like to exclude all sticky post from my query but when I do it, it breaks my pagination. In the following code, when I remove the "**'post__not_in' => $sticky**" my pagination works like a charm...

Any advice would be much appreciated !

Cheers.

```
/* Exculde STICKY from the main QUERY */
function exclude_cat(){
    if (is_home()) {
        $paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
        $sticky = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );
        $args = array(
        'category__not_in' => array( 71 ),
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
        'post__not_in' => $sticky,
        'paged' => $paged
        );
        query_posts($args);
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need the `post__not_in` arg if you're using `ignore_sticky_posts`(`caller_get_posts` pre 3.1)... or at least it shouldn't be needed.

Comment: If I remove the post__not_in arg, sticky posts appear in my query.

Comment: What version are you on, you'll need to use `caller_get_posts` instead of `ignore_sticky_posts` if you're running anything less than WordPress 3.1 (eg. 3.0.5)

Comment: I'm on 3.0.5 so I replaced `ignore_sticky_posts` by `caller_get_posts`, however if I remove the line `post__not_in` the pagination appears but the sticky posts too... Very frustrating.

Comment: This `get_query_var('page')` should actually be `get_query_var('paged')`, see if changing that fixes the problem, alongside the other changes suggested.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by @t31os in the comments, `get_query_var('page')` should actually be `get_query_var('paged')`.